# How to dynamically change active css for menubar using while loop and jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I make a loop to load my collapse data. The css style does not change.

**PHP**

```
<li class="nav-item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Title">
        <a class="nav-link nav-link-collapse collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseComponent" data-parent="#exampleAccordion">
            <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i><span class="nav-link-text"> Title </span></a>

    <?php

        $category_query = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE ... ";
        $stmt = $heidisql->query($category_query);

        $row_count = $heidisql->query('SELECT count(*) from category WHERE ... ');
        $data_exists = $row_count->fetchColumn();

        echo '<ul class="nav-second-level collapse" id="collapseComponent">';

        if ($data_exists > 0){
            while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $test_id = $row["id"];
                $test_title = $row["title"];
                $test_link = $row["link"];

                echo '<li class="nav-item second-level-collapse">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="category-'.$test_id.'" href="'.$test_link.'">'.$test_title.'</a></li>';
            }
            echo "</ul></li>";

        }

    ?>
```

The loop work but I cannot make it do dynamically change css base on which link I'm on.
**Jquery code**

```
<script>

var loc = window.location.pathname;

$('.nav-second-level').find('a.nav-link').each(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active', $(this).attr('href') == loc);
});

</script>
```

**CSS** For change the style

```
.nav-second-level > li.nav-item a.active {
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
color: black;
}
```

I used to do it like that

```
$menuLinkid = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],".php");

if ($menuLinkid == "test") {
$menu = "active-Sidebar-Link";
?>
```

html

```
<li class="nav-item second-level-collapse">
    <a class="nav-link <?php echo $menu; ?>" id="category-'.$test_id.'" href="'.$test_link.'">'.$test_title.'</a></li>

.navbar-collapse > ul > li.nav-item a.active-Sidebar-Link{
 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
 color:black;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you're using `toggleClass()` while you just need to `addClass('active')` And No need to use `.each()` You can directly use `$('.nav-second-level a.nav-link[href="'+loc+'"]')` like so

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var loc = window.location.href;
  $('.nav-second-level a.nav-link').removeClass('active').filter('[href="'+loc+'"]').addClass('active');
});
```

And don't forget to wrap your code in `$(document).ready()`

Notice: maybe the problem comes from lowercase and upper case letters and white spaces as well to check this you can use

```
$test_link = strtolower(trim($row["link"]));
```

And

```
var loc = window.location.href.toLowerCase().trim();
```

Comment: look @JOnathaFlint We don't care right now with css style .. we care about the active class is already added to our element or not .. so please check it in your console that active class added or not

Comment: im getting an alert

Comment: nope, still the change. I can click on my link fine, but the current active link style remain the same. If I do this echo '<li class="nav-item second-level-collapse">
                    <a class="nav-link active_Sidebar-Link" id="category-'.$test_id.'" href="'.$test_link.'">'.$test_title.'</a></li>'; all of my link css style change

Comment: @JOnathaFlint updated answer with `removeClass().filter()` .. you can changing `active` class with your active one

Comment: i just check element, the class active does not appear at all